# help in adding a http link in script editor - cant get it to work

Tags: content-editor-web-part, script

Im trying to add the link below to open in a new windows using showSPDialog

```
 newRows +="<p><span><a onclick='/showSPDialog(\' + viewurl + \');/'  href='#'><img src='/Test/SiteAssets/sendmail.png'/  title=" + email + "></a></span></p>";
                        newRows +="</li>";
```

But i keep getting error ; missing character bla bla..

No idea what im missing .
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

updated code below:

```
 newRows +="<p><span><a href='#' onclick='showSPDialog(" + viewurl + ");'>MS SharePoint Site</a></span></p>";
```

But getting error missing ) after argument list - error on the :

showSPDialog(https://

Comment: What are the forward slashes for? Wouldn't that just make the attribute values into regular expressions?

Comment: sorry pasted the wrong one: See my update in the Original Post

Comment: If `viewurl` is a string, and not the name of a variable your code will not work. The end result would be something like calling `showSPDialog(http://google.com)`, which will not work very well. It will work if you have something like `var viewurl = '"http://google.com"';`. But wouldn't it be better to use some sort of templating?